# Laravel, why my define route error 404 not found?

Tags: laravel

i want to ask something.. i have these routes

```
Route::group(['as' => 'ecommerce.'], function() {

    // ================================= AUTH ============================================
    // LOGIN & LOGOUT
    Route::get('/login', [AuthController::class, 'loginForm'])->name('login.index');
    Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'postLogin'])->name('login.post');

    // REGISTER
    Route::get('/register', [AuthController::class, 'registerForm'])->name('register.index');
    Route::post('/register', [AuthController::class, 'postRegister'])->name('register.post');
    Route::get('/verify/{token}', [AuthController::class, 'verifyEmail'])->name('register.verify');

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'members'], function() {
        Route::get('/logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout'])->name('logout');

            // CART
        Route::get('/cart', [CartController::class, 'index'])->name('cart.index');
        Route::group(['as' => 'product.'], function() {
            Route::post('/getActionCart', [FrontProductDetailController::class, 'getActionCart'])->name('detail.action');
            Route::post('/cart/store', [FrontProductDetailController::class, 'addToCart'])->name('detail.store');
        });
    });

    Route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('index');
    Route::get('/{categoryParentSlug}/{categoryChildSlug}', [FrontProductController::class, 'getProductByCategory'])->name('product.category');
    Route::get('/{categoryParent}/{categoryChild}/{slug}', [ProductController::class, 'getDetailProduct'])->name('product.detail');
    Route::get('/products', [FrontProductController::class, 'getProductList'])->name('product.index');
    Route::get('/{brandSlug}', [FrontProductController::class, 'getProductByBrand'])->name('product.brand');

});
```

And its work as i want. But, when i changing route order like

```
Route::group(['as' => 'ecommerce.'], function() {
    Route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('index');
    Route::get('/{categoryParentSlug}/{categoryChildSlug}', [FrontProductController::class, 'getProductByCategory'])->name('product.category');
    Route::get('/{categoryParent}/{categoryChild}/{slug}', [ProductController::class, 'getDetailProduct'])->name('product.detail');
    Route::get('/products', [FrontProductController::class, 'getProductList'])->name('product.index');
    Route::get('/{brandSlug}', [FrontProductController::class, 'getProductByBrand'])->name('product.brand');

    // ================================= AUTH ============================================
    // LOGIN & LOGOUT
    Route::get('/login', [AuthController::class, 'loginForm'])->name('login.index');
    Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, 'postLogin'])->name('login.post');

    // REGISTER
    Route::get('/register', [AuthController::class, 'registerForm'])->name('register.index');
    Route::post('/register', [AuthController::class, 'postRegister'])->name('register.post');
    Route::get('/verify/{token}', [AuthController::class, 'verifyEmail'])->name('register.verify');

    Route::group(['middleware' => 'members'], function() {
        Route::get('/logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout'])->name('logout');

            // CART
        Route::get('/cart', [CartController::class, 'index'])->name('cart.index');
        Route::group(['as' => 'product.'], function() {
            Route::post('/getActionCart', [FrontProductDetailController::class, 'getActionCart'])->name('detail.action');
            Route::post('/cart/store', [FrontProductDetailController::class, 'addToCart'])->name('detail.store');
        });
    });
});
```

all route after `========================AUTH========================` always showing 404 not found, how can it happen?

i want to clean my order routes, but i can't because of these errors.. i think i have wrong with middleware, but its look fine.

Comment: Because your  routes are conflict with `/{brandSlug}`, you cant use same uri pattern, when your method are same. Uncomment this line `Route::get('/{brandSlug}',... ` now you can access `/login` and `/register`

Comment: already doing that

Comment: @Droid so i need to configure my uri pattern first? like brands it should write like `Route::get('/brand/{brandSlug});` ?

Comment: Yes, are you still facing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

typically this is a result of having wild-card routes registered first

```
Route::get('/{categoryParentSlug}/{categoryChildSlug}', [FrontProductController::class, 'getProductByCategory'])->name('product.category');
```

How is it supposed to identify a URI such as /login when it's assuming that the first URI should be interpreted as a categoryParentSlug when the categoryParentSlug route is being registered prior to the /login route? It doesn't make the discernment, so since it can't find a categoryParentSlug called "login" it will return a 404.

Place any routes where the first URI is a wild-card at the bottom of the route-list for the prefix/route-group or create a new route-group for those routes to avoid any conflicts.

Another consideration when utilizing slugs is to make sure that the primary-key for the model is set to use the slug for route-model-binding.

Comment: ok, it seems make sense because i handler when click detail products like `$currentParent = Category::whereSlug($categoryParentSlug)->first();
        $currentChild  = Category::whereSlug($categoryChildSlug)->first();
        if($currentParent == "" || $currentChild == "") abort(404); `

Answer (score -1):

Have you got clear all cache in your Laravel Application ?

php artisan cache:clear && php artisan route:cache

Comment: yes, i already tried php artisan cache:clear && php artisan route:cache..

Comment: and you find your route : php artisan route:list

Comment: yes, i found that route in php artisan route:list. The url, action, middleware or even name is correct, but when i click it showing 404 not found.

Comment: Clear cache from your navigator, can you try access to the url from url directly?

Comment: it cant, i already test input url ```lara_ecommerce.test/cart``` and it showing 404 not found when it should showing login page since ***cart*** is in members middleware